# R language Functions within lists

Tags: r, list, object

G'Day, I am a newbie at R and I have GOOGLED and read books and had lots of play, but I can't seem to figure out if what I am doing is implemented.  It compiles (no interpreter spit) and can be called (again no spit), it just doesn't seem to want to do anything.

OK.  SYNOPSIS.

I read that lists in R are the OBJECTS of other languages.  So just for a Saturday and Sunday play I have been trying to get this to work.

```
GLOBAL <- list( counter = 1,
                locked = FALSE,
                important_value = 42,
                copy_of_important_value = 42,
                lock = function() { GLOBAL$locked = TRUE },
                unlock = function() { GLOBAL$locked = FALSE },
                is_locked = function() { return(GLOBAL$locked )},
                visit = function() { GLOBAL$counter <- GLOBAL$counter + 1 })

> GLOBAL$locked
[1] FALSE
>
```

This works...

```
> GLOBAL$locked <- TRUE
> GLOBAL$locked
[1] TRUE
>
```

This does not

```
> GLOBAL$unlock()
> GLOBAL$locked
[1] TRUE
>
```

Has R got a $this or $self construct?  None of this generates any errors.  Just doesn't seem to want to do anything!  (functions that is).  I suppose I could set up a function as a routing access table, but I thought the encapsulation would be nifty.

Second question. It has been mentioned to me several times that R MUST keep all data in memory, and that is a limitation.  Does that include swp on *NIX systems?  I mean, if you had a humungus matrix could you just add some swap to make it fit?

Sorry for dumb newbie questions

Comment: You are going to want to read about all the actual OOP systems in R as they will likely be preferable to what you are attempting here. [Link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html)

Comment: See package ff for 2nd question.

Comment: In brief, lists do not facilitate encapsulation.  Functions in lists do not have special access to data in the list. There are other facilities for object orientation. Like S4 classes with their slots and accessor functions.

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using proto objects:

```
library(proto) # home page at http://r-proto.googlecode.com

GLOBAL <- proto( counter = 1,
                 locked = FALSE,
                 important_value = 42,
                 copy_of_important_value = 42,
                 lock = function(.) { .$locked = TRUE },
                 unlock = function(.) { .$locked = FALSE },
                 is_locked = function(.) { return(.$locked )},
                 visit = function(.) { .$counter <- .$counter + 1 })

GLOBAL$locked <- TRUE
GLOBAL$unlock() 
GLOBAL$locked
## FALSE
```

Comment: Wow!  I NEED to look at that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The S3 way of doing things.

```
GLOBAL <- list(counter=1, locked=FALSE,
    important_value=42, copy_of_important_value=42)

class(GLOBAL) <- "foo"

lock <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("lock")
lock.foo <- function(x)
{
    x$locked <- TRUE
    x
}

unlock <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("unlock")
unlock.foo <- function(x)
{
    x$locked <- FALSE
    x
}

is_locked <- function(x) x$locked

visit <- function(x)
{
    x$counter <- x$counter + 1
    x
}


GLOBAL <- lock(GLOBAL)   # locked is now TRUE
GLOBAL <- unlock(GLOBAL) # locked is now FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks!   You lot are pretty quick!

Answer (score 2):

There's also the enclosure method

```
getGlobal <- function() {
    counter <- 1
    locked <- FALSE
    important_value <- 42
    list(
        is_locked = function() locked,
        lock = function() locked<<-TRUE,
        unlock = function() locked<<-FALSE,
        visit = function() {counter <<- counter + 1 }
    )
}
```

And then you would use

```
GLOBAL <- getGlobal()

GLOBAL$is_locked()    
# [1] FALSE
GLOBAL$lock()
GLOBAL$is_locked()    
# [1] TRUE
```

So the state is stored in the enclosure and `getGlobal` returns a list of functions you can use to access those variables not otherwise exposed.

Comment: That and the proto thingy looks like what I want to do.  I can't thank you lot enough.  I have only been learning R for a few days and I ran out of hints!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happened because

- R doesn't have any variables to go get because they way you have it,  `=` does not mean assignment has occurred inside the `list()`. So the only object in the global environment is `GLOBAL`. The way you're using `=` right now is assigning the list names to the left-hand side, and they are subsequently accessed with the `$` operator.
- Your functions are not returning a value as they're written.  `GLOBAL$locked()` will not return a value if  `GLOBAL$locked <- FALSE` is all you have inside the body of the function that calls it.  So I wrap it in parentheses, and is returns our desire values.

So we just need to assign `locked` to the global environment first, then `<<-` will reassign it.

I shortened your list a bit.  Here's a look:

```
> GLOBAL <- list(locked = assign("locked", FALSE, parent.frame()),
                 lock = function() { (GLOBAL$locked <<- TRUE) },
                 unlock = function() { (GLOBAL$locked <<- 'HELLO') },
                 is_locked = function() { return(NULL) })
> GLOBAL$locked
[1] FALSE
> GLOBAL$lock()
[1] TRUE
> GLOBAL$unlock()
[1] "HELLO"
> GLOBAL$is_locked()
NULL
```

Yes, a list has its own environment, separate from the global environment.  An example of this is

```
> l <- list(x = 5, y = 10)
> within(l, {
      f <- function(x) 2 * x
  })
$x
[1] 5

$y
[1] 10

$f
function (x) 
2 * x
<environment: 0xb041278>
```

but we are currently in the global environment

```
> environment()
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

It's funny you should ask this question because I just asked [a question about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213983/explanation-of-how-this-complex-function-works) yesterday. MrFlick provided a very good explanation on that question.

Comment: I shall visit that list right away!  Thank you for sharing it, and for your explanation.  Me go code now!